# Title of application menu in top bar shows Java package path

Tags: 20.04, java, application-development

I have a self written Java application. I set the frame title with `JFrame.setTitle`. When I run it under Ubuntu 20.04, the application menu in the top bar shows the Java package path as shown in this screenshot.

[image: top bar showing the java package path]

How I start the application doesn't matter: directly from the development environment (Eclipse), double-clicking the generated jar file, or from command line (`java -jar LineRacer.jar`)), all are the same.

Does anyone know how I can change this?

Answer (score 1):

The asker of [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219169/javafx-application-name-on-gnome) fixed it for Swing with the following code which worked for me too:

```java
// Set name in system menubar for Gnome (and Linux)
if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("linux")) {
  try {
    Toolkit xToolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Field awtAppClassNameField = xToolkit.getClass().getDeclaredField("awtAppClassName");
    awtAppClassNameField.setAccessible(true);
    awtAppClassNameField.set(xToolkit, "MyApp"); 
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO
  }
}
```